# i need postgresql mathematical select

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I need idea for sql select on this. 
I have a table with this columns:

```
ID  type  quan price
 1     1    5     6.5
 1     1    4     7
 1     2    5     10
 1     1    5     6
```

I need to run a query with following condition:

```
fir i = 1 to 4
if type = 1
     rprice = (rprice*rquan + price*quan)/(rquan+quan)
     rquan  = rquan  + quan
else
 rquan  = rquan  - quan
end
next
```

The type can be 1 or 2
For ID 1 I need as result rquan and rprice
The sumary result must be : 
rquan=9     rprice=6.32

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 case when type = 1 
 then (rprice*rquan + price*quan)/(rquan+quan)
 else price
 end as "rprice"
,case when type = 1 
 then rquan  + quan
 else quan
 end as "rquan"
from "table_name"
```

Comment: No , in this case I need only one result!  With your idea , for every one row  i will have some result .At last result must be  rquan  9     rprice  6.32

Comment: sorry - I don't understand... can you clearly show the expected result? not in words - screenshot or so

Comment: As result I need  rquan=8   rprice = 6.32 because  5 + 4 - 5 + 5=9    and as result from the formula rprice = 6.32

Comment: I see - you want window function comparing current against previous. this can be done with `lag(field) over ()`, but I would recommend you refractor your formula to smth like `sum(case when type =1 then quan else -1*quan end)` or even group by type and them run mathematical function against WHOLE column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, you can do this with cumulative sums and/or aggregation.  For instance, for `rquan`:

```
select rquan
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 1 then quan else - quan end) over (order by ??) as rquan_row        
      from table t
     ) t
order by ?? desc
limit 1;
```

This can actually be simplified to a single conditional aggregation, but you seem to want this quantity row-by-row.

I don't fully understand the calculation for `rprice`.  I can see what the formula is, but it doesn't make sense.  An average price for the data would be 6 not 6.32.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom aggregate to do this. The syntax is rather strange in places, though.

```
create schema so32264410;

create table so32264410.data(seqno serial primary key, id int, type int, quan int, price numeric);
insert into so32264410.data(id, type, quan, price) values(1, 1, 5, 6.5),(1, 1, 4, 7),(1, 2, 5, 10),(1, 1, 5, 6);

-- define a type to hold the aggregation and a function to perform reduction
create type so32264410.calc_type as (quan int, price numeric);
create function so32264410.calc_sfunc(state so32264410.calc_type, type int, quan int, price numeric) returns so32264410.calc_type immutable language plpgsql as $$
declare
  rquan int;
  rprice numeric;
begin
  rquan := state.quan;
  rprice := state.price;
  if type = 1 then
    rprice := (rprice * rquan + price * quan) / (rquan + quan);
    rquan := rquan + quan;
  else
    rquan := rquan - quan;
  end if;
  state := row(rquan, rprice)::so32264410.calc_type;
  return state;
end
$$;
-- bind the reducing function, state type and initial state into an aggregate
create aggregate so32264410.calc(int, int, numeric) (sfunc = so32264410.calc_sfunc, stype = so32264410.calc_type, initcond = '(0,0)');

select so32264410.calc(type, quan, price) from so32264410.data where id = 1;
```